# Logout from ActiveAdmin destroy other sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, activeadmin

I am using devise with activeadmin and one other model.
If I open both interfaces on browser and logout from one it will also destroy other sessions.

```
Started GET "/admin/logout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-11-03 19:45:25 +0500
Processing by ActiveAdmin::Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"6rqzYcjQNgm8sOcAy2ItHvqGWTYyUBEK2tE+hJi8Ti0E25qJLR+vdA9W++HHtFaD3CpBtnNAn6xbhS6mr8YLTQ=="}
Teacher Load (30.4ms)  SELECT  `teachers`.* FROM `teachers` WHERE `teachers`.`id` = ?  ORDER BY `teachers`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
AdminUser Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `admin_users`.* FROM `admin_users` WHERE `admin_users`.`id` = ?  ORDER BY `admin_users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
(0.0ms)  COMMIT
SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
(0.0ms)  COMMIT
```

Comment: What do you mean by other sessions?

Comment: @nayiaw: He means that when he destroys the Teachers session it also destroys the AdminUser session.

Comment: yes @Jess you are right

Answer (score 5):

By default when `Devise::SessionsController#destroy` is invoked it will destroy the sessions from all scopes. This is configurable via `sign_out_all_scopes`. So to disable it, set it to false:

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
config.sign_out_all_scopes = false
```